# How to append output values of a function to a new empty list?

Tags: python, function, loops, append

My aim is to create a function, list_powers, and use a for loop to take a list and return a new list (power_list) where each element is exponentiated to a specified power.

I have moved the return statement appropriately in order to collect all topowers in power_list and return them but it still returns None. How do I change it so that it returns the list of powers?

```
def list_powers(collection = [], power = 2):
    power_list = []
    
    for elem in collection:
        topower = elem ** power
        power_list.append(topower)
    return power_list.append(topower)
```

test:

```
list_powers([2, 4, 1, 5, 12], power = 2)
```

output:

```
None
```

Comment: Your function returns whatever and whenever you ask it to return. In this case, you asked it to return immediately after it calculated the first `elem ** power`. It does exactly what you asked it to do. If you want to collect all `topower`s in `power_list` and return that list _after_ you've finished the loop, move your return statement appropriately

Comment: I knew there had to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` leaves the function. You have to return after the loop, not unconditional in the loop. And of course you don't want to return the last value for `topower` but the full list.

```
def list_powers(iterable, power = 2):
    power_list = []

    for elem in iterable:
        topower = elem ** power
        power_list.append(topower)

    return power_list

print(list_powers([2, 4, 1, 5, 12]))
```

The shorter version uses a list comprehension

```
def list_powers(iterable, power = 2):
    return [elem ** power for elem in iterable]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `return topower` it stop the function therefore it will only return one value. If you want to return a list you should do `return power_list` and outside of the local scope.